# Is it possible to do regression discontinuity (RDD) with different treatment intensities?

Tags: econometrics, regression-discontinuity

My question arises from an assignment rule which gives monetary transfers to cities with a population of less than 25,000 inhabitants. However, the transfer varies between cities depending on its respective population and poverty levels. With that context, is it possible to run an RDD? If so, which literature is suggested to read? Thanks in advance and forgive my poor English.